# Call to undefined function app\models\password_verify()

Tags: php, yii2

появляется ошибка при авторизации (на хостинге. на локалном этой ошибки нет)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Функция `password_verify` определена в php, начиная с версии 5.5.
Вам стоит обновить php, чтобы пользоваться этой функцией.

---

Не по теме вопроса:

*Конструкция `$a ? true : false` в большинстве случаев($a - уже булевое выражение) бесполезна и меняется на `$a`, в остальных случаях - `boolval($a)`*

*Не стоит экранировать данные перед записью в базу. Данные должны храниться как есть. Для разных отображений потом применяется разное экранирование. Тот же email вам приходится лишний раз экранировать, чтоб найти, разэкранировать, чтобы отправить на него письмо и т.п.*

Comment: спасибо. у хостинга версия php 5.4.16 (native). я могу изменить сам или это сделает администратор

Comment: Если предложение без вопросительного знака - это вопрос, то мой ответ на него - я не знаю. Я сам не пользуюсь хостингами, да и не знаю какой именно у Вас.